# Javascript color change <div> on condition

Tags: javascript, if-statement, switch-statement, setinterval

So I have this block of code and I need the color of the div to "flicker" between purple and white for the condition "MECHANIC ON LINE". I know that outside a switch statement that the code I am implementing normally works, but inside a switch statement I am not sure. Also this is on a company server and I am unsure how some of the processes in the back-end may be handling the updates of the page. Regardless, if anyone has insight on if I am incorrect on implementing my code in the switch statement please let me know. Furthermore, the first snippet of code is taken from the bigger snippet below, it is the piece of the switch statement I am concerned with. Last, I also wanted to mention I have set the time intervals to different intergers from eachother, for example "setInterval(function, 10 * 1000), setInterval(function, 20 * 2000)".

```
                    case "MECHANIC ON LINE":
                        colorTitle[i].style.color = 'rgb(127.5, 127.5, 127.5)';
                        if(colorBackground[l].style.background === 'rgb(123,31,162)') {
                            setInterval(colorBackground[l].style.background = 'rgb(255,255,255)',10 * 1000);
                        } else {
                            setInterval(colorBackground[l].style.background = 'rgb(123,31,162)',10 * 1000);
                        }
                    break;
```

```
for(var i = 0; i < colorTitle.length; i++) {
            for(var l = i; l < colorBackground.length; l++) {
                switch(colorTitle[i].textContent) {
                    case "RUNNING":
                    colorTitle[i].style.color = 'rgb(0, 255, 0)';
                    colorBackground[l].style.background = 'rgb(0, 255, 0)';
                    break;
                    case "LINE DOWN":
                    colorTitle[i].style.color = 'rgb(255, 0, 0)';
                    colorBackground[l].style.background = 'rgb(255, 0, 0)';
                    break;
                    case "OFFLINE":
                    colorTitle[i].style.color = 'rgb(127.5, 127.5, 127.5)';
                    colorBackground[l].style.background = 'rgb(127.5, 127.5, 127.5)';
                    break;
                    case "MECHANIC ON LINE":
                        colorTitle[i].style.color = 'rgb(127.5, 127.5, 127.5)';
                        if(colorBackground[l].style.background === 'rgb(123,31,162)') {
                            setInterval(colorBackground[l].style.background = 'rgb(255,255,255)',10 * 1000);
                        } else {
                            setInterval(colorBackground[l].style.background = 'rgb(123,31,162)',10 * 1000);
                        }
                    break;
                    default:
                    colorTitle[i].style.color = 'rgb(255, 255, 255)';
                    colorBackground[l].style.background = 'rgb(255, 255, 255)';
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: This sounds like it would be better suited for animations based on classes vs. controlling the colors manually, is that possible?

Comment: I agree but it would take a restructure of a lot of other code which may not be an option. Also I think that even if it was class based animation it may still run into the same issue inside the switch statement.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that the logic to choose between the two colours is inside the switch statement, which is only executed once. So what you're doing is setting the interval to keep setting the same colour repeatedly.

The logic to switch between the two colours needs to be inside the callback function of every repeated interval. Something like this:

```
case "MECHANIC ON LINE":
  colorTitle[i].style.color = 'rgb(127.5, 127.5, 127.5)';
  colorBackground[l].style.background = 'rgb(255,255,255)';
  setInterval(function() { flicker(colorBackground[l]); }, 10 * 1000);
break;
```

Then you'll need to define the function somewhere:

```
function flicker(target) {
  if(target.style.background === 'rgb(123,31,162)') {
    target.style.background = 'rgb(255,255,255)';
  } else {
    target.style.background = 'rgb(123,31,162)';
  }
}
```

Because objects and arrays are passed by reference, the original `colorBackground` will be updated even though it looks like you've created a new object called `target`.

Comment: Thank you, I will try running this on the server tomorrow! I will keep you posted to let you know if this solution worked for me.

Comment: I get an error of "cannot read style of undefined". This only happens when I run it in my Crimson server though, the code works locally to change colors but not flicker back and fourth.

Comment: I've updated the answer - we weren't setting an initial value for the background color (see the first block of code).

Comment: (Edit), I could get it to flicker back and fourth the problem was that there are no spaces between the numbers (123,31,162). Simply including the space between the numbers as so (123, 31, 162) made it flicker locally. I have yet to figure out my issue on the server.

Comment: Oh I see, the edit is for the server issue, I will give that a shot. Thank you very much by the way, I really like the solution you have provided.

Comment: Sorry was going to try to include code in comment but could not. We got the issue of undefined to go away but on the Server, flickering is still an issue. I am going to try to implement a few different iterations of your solution above. I will let you know if I find success.

Comment: I just fixed that block of code again which may or may not help.

Comment: Hey so I wanted to keep you updated. On the server I am having an issue with undefined again, I believe I know why. So on the first iteration of the switch statement we define the variable and it is caught, but unless the switch statement is run again, I believe it causes the variable to lose scope inside the setInterval function. That is my theory so far.